# What's the correct way to position three views (one left, one centered & expanded, one right) on Android?

Tags: android, layout

I have three views, all positioned on a horizontal line, aligned vertically to the center. The whole thing should obviously expand to 100% width of the device.

- **left** - fixed width, floating to the left, with a margin on both sides
- **center** - expands as much as possible, with margins on both sides
- **right** - fixed width, floating to the right, with margins on both sides

Here's how it should look

[image: screenshot]

What is the most simple and idiomatic way to represent this on Android? If there are compatibility limitations, I'm ok with 4.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a horizontal `LinearLayout` as the container of the three items. Use `android:layout_weight="1"` on the middle item to have it absorb all leftover width after the base widths of the three items are taken care of. Use `android:layout_marginRight` and related attributes to set your margins. Set `android:gravity="center_vertical"` on the `LinearLayout` to center the three items within the height of the `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/myViewId1"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/myViewId1"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

I think with this you should be ok, if got any problem with the center view apply android:marginTop="10dp" and will be perfect. Good Luck